# Convert lag, Partition by in SQL to LINQ Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an existing table #temp with below format

```
#temp(id bigint, pid varchar(50), pdt date)
```

How do i convert the below SQL Query to Linq Lambda

```
create table #tempResultSet
(
    id bigint,
    pid varchar(20),
    pdt date, 
    pdt1 date, 
    daydiff as datediff(day,pdt,pdt1)
)
insert into #tempResultSet
SELECT id, pid, pdt, 
isnull(lead(pdt) OVER (PARTITION BY pid  ORDER BY pdt),
lag(pdt) OVER (PARTITION BY pid  ORDER BY pdt)) pdt1 
FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming #temp and #tempResultSet are both configured properly, you can use linq2db's [support for window functions](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-(Analytic-Functions).html) to get what you want.

Below is a snippet of what I believe would be the correct syntax in this case, though I haven't tested it, and I don't have experience using linq2db. I hope it helps:

```
var q =
from temp in dbContext.Temp
select new TempResultSet
{
    Id = temp.id,
    Pid = temp.pid,
    Pdt = temp.pdt,
    IsNull = Sql.Ext.Lead(temp.pdt)
        .Over()
        .PartitionBy(temp.pid)
        .OrderBy(temp.pdt)
        .ToValue() is null,
    Pdt1 = Sql.Ext.Lag(temp.pdt)
        .Over()
        .PartitionBy(temp.pid)
        .OrderBy(temp.pdt)
};

dbContext.AddRange(q.ToArray());
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```